# Regex created via new RegExp(myString) not working (backslashes)

Tags: javascript, regex

So, I'm trying to write a regex that matches all numbers. Here is that regex:

```
/\b[\d \.]+\b/g
```

And I try to use it on the string:

```
100 two 100
```

And everything works fine; it matches both of the numbers.

But I want to rewrite the regex in the form:

```
new RegExp(pattern,modifiers)
```

Because I think it looks clearer.
So I write it like this:

```
new RegExp('\b[\d \.]+\b','g')
```

But now it won't match the former test string. I have tried everything, but I just can't get it to work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your problem is that the backslash in a string has a special meaning; if you want a backslash in your regexp, you first need to get literal backslashes in the string passed to the regex:

```
new RegExp('\\b[\\d \\.]+\\b','g');
```

Note that this is a pretty bad (permissive) regex, as it will match `". . . "` as a 'number', or `"1 1...3 42"`. Better might be:

```
/-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?\b/
```

[image]

Note that this matches odd things like `0000.3` also does not match:

- Leading `+`
- Scientific notation, e.g. `1.3e7`
- Missing leading digit, e.g. `.4`

Also, note that using the RegExp constructor is (marginally) slower and certainly less idiomatic than using a RegExp literal. Using it is only a good idea when you need to constructor your RegExp from supplied strings. Most anyone with more than passing familiarity with JavaScript will find the `/.../` notation fully clear.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that you can use `new RegExp(String.raw\`\b[\d \.]+\b\`, "g")` instead of manually escaping each special character. Notice the backticks following String.raw instead of quotation marks.