# Javascript invalid regular expresion error in NW.js

Tags: javascript, regex, nwjs

I have a regular expression which I need to test with a string, it works when I test it online

```
^(?![.])^[.a-zA-Z0-9]*(?<!\.)$
```

You can test it : https://regex101.com/r/bomm5g/1/

But when I write a code for it, I get this error

```
Invalid regular expression: /^(?![.])^[.a-zA-Z0-9]*(?<!.)$/: Invalid group
```

The code is as below

```
var regex = new RegExp("^(?![.])^[.a-zA-Z0-9]*(?<!\.)$");
regex.test(inputvalue);
```

How can I get this to work ?

Comment: There is no test subject in your regex101.

Comment: Did you read the error that is mentioned by regex101.com (_"`?` The preceding token is not quantifiable"_)?

Comment: The code you have posted doesn't throw that error. Which browser are you using? Also, you need to escape backslashes if you are using `RegExp` constructor: [Regex created via new RegExp(myString) not working (backslashes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4914484)

Comment: I ran your code in Chrome's console and I got no error. However Regexpal.com says : `Lookbehind is not supported in JS`.

Comment: @adiga I am using NW.js(nodewebkit previously) which is chromium based.  I don't have any backslashes in the expression as such.

Comment: There is a backslash here: `(?<!\.)`

Comment: Many browsers, including Firefox and Edge don't support lookbehind.

Answer (score 0):

@Abbas just try this

```
var regex = new RegExp(/^(?![.])^[.a-zA-Z0-9]*(?<!\.)$/);
```

instead of var regex = new RegExp("^(?![.])^[.a-zA-Z0-9]*(?

Comment: Got the same error

Comment: `new RegExp` expects a string as parameter!

Comment: @Toto it also takes the pattern. It's working fine for me.